# Pig Distinct vs Group By

Tags: apache-pig

I am wanting to return the distinct rows in a large pig relation -- Is it faster to do a distinct on the columns, or to group by the columns, and then return the group?

Exmaple Data  in relation A:

```
id_a    id_b    counts 
GG       AA       29 
GG       AA       29 
GG       BC       34 
GG       BC       34 
AA       DD       44
```

Distinct Example:

```
distinct_A = distinct A; 
dump distinct_A
```

vs

Group by example:

```
grouped_A = group A by (id_a,id_b,counts); 
projected_group = foreach grouped_A generate group; 
dump projected_group
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your version of Pig, but for recent versions **DISTINCT should be faster**.

> In pig 0.1.x, DISTINCT is just GROUP BY/PROJECT under the hood. In pig 0.2.0 it is not, and it is much faster and more efficient (depending on your key cardinality, up to 20x faster in pig team's tests). Therefore, the use of DISTINCT is recommended over GROUP BY - GENERATE.

Source: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/cookbook.html#Prefer+DISTINCT+over+GROUP+BY+-+GENERATE

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `grouped_A = group A by (id_a,id_b,counts);` ?

Also I would recommend testing it to find out.  I suspect that Distinct will be quicker. But the best way to do it is buy using LIMIT to take a big enough dataset that you can tell the difference in time taken but not too big that it will take as long as processing all of your data.